# python: urllib2 how to send cookie with urlopen request

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to use  urllib2 to open url and to send specific cookie text to the server. E.g. I want to open site [Solve chess problems](http://chess-problems.prg), with a specific cookie, e.g. search=1. How do I do it?

I am trying to do the following:

```
import urllib2
(need to add cookie to the request somehow)
urllib2.urlopen("http://chess-problems.prg")
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Cookie is just another HTTP header.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'cookiename=cookievalue'))
f = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

See [urllib2 examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples) for other ways how to add HTTP headers to your request.

There are more ways how to handle cookies. Some modules like [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) try to behave like web browser - remember what cookies did you get previously and automatically send them again in following requests.

Comment: If you have multiple cookies, you need to join them in a single header value, separated by a semicolon. For example, if you have a dictionary of cookie values called `cookievals`, then use `opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', "; ".join('%s=%s' % (k,v) for k,v in cookievals.items())))`.

Comment: What if they're using other params to urlopen?

Answer (score 56):

Maybe using [cookielib.CookieJar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects) can help you. For instance when posting to a page containing a form:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
# input-type values from the html form
formdata = { "username" : username, "password": password, "form-id" : "1234" }
data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(formdata)
response = opener.open("https://page.com/login.php", data_encoded)
content = response.read()
```

**EDIT:**

After Piotr's comment I'll elaborate a bit. From the docs:

> The CookieJar class stores HTTP cookies. It extracts cookies from HTTP
>   requests, and returns them in HTTP responses. CookieJar instances
>   automatically expire contained cookies when necessary. Subclasses are
>   also responsible for storing and retrieving cookies from a file or
>   database.

So whatever requests you make with your `CookieJar` instance, all cookies will be handled automagically. Kinda like your browser does :)

I can only speak from my own experience and my 99% use-case for cookies is to receive a cookie and then need to send it with all subsequent requests in that session.
The code above handles just that, and it does so transparently.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost you are right, I do not send a specific cookie with this code :) I am assuming I will receive one when POSTing, and the `CookieJar` instance will handle it for me on all relevant domains from then on.

Comment: The OP clearly states *(…) to send specific cookie text (…)* so this is not an answer.

Answer (score 13):

You might want to take a look at the excellent HTTP Python library called [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). It makes every task involving HTTP a bit easier than urllib2. From [Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) section of quickstart guide:

> To send your own cookies to the server, you can use the cookies parameter:

```
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')

>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies=cookies)
>>> r.text
'{"cookies": {"cookies_are": "working"}}'
```

Comment: It's based on `urllib3`, it supports pooling of connections like urllib3, and persists cookies, headers - see [`Requests Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). It's beautiful!

Answer (score 5):

Use [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html). The linked doc page provides examples at the end. You'll also find a tutorial [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml).

Comment: In the tutorial they are saving cookie after receiving it from server isn't it?

Comment: They are both saving cookies retrieved from the server and returning them back to the server, since this is usually how cookies work. If you want to do something out of the ordinary, then you'll have to dig a little deeper into the library. I'm pretty sure it'll support whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not working since the `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3. 
You need to do

```
from urllib import request
opener = request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'cookiename=cookievalue'))
f = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```