# Consecutive requests with python Requests.Session() not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I was trying to do this,

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
login_data = dict(userName='user', password='pwd')
ra=s.post('http://example/checklogin.php', data=login_data)
print ra.content
print ra.headers
ans = dict(answer='5')
f=s.cookies
r=s.post('http://example/level1.php',data=ans,cookies=f)
print r.content
```

But the second post request returns a 404 error, can someone help me why ?

Comment: it didn't find the page. check the url

Comment: If run only second request everything works as supposed?

Comment: url is right. @zero323 second request is available only to users who have successfully logged in.

Comment: @Paco the url is correct as it opens in the browser

Comment: Upon trying all the answers I found this to work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41131985/2041707

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of `requests`, the `sessions` object comes equipped with `Cookie Persistence`, look at the requests Sessions ojbects [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).
So you don't need add the cookie artificially.
Just

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
login_data = dict(userName='user', password='pwd')
ra=s.post('http://example/checklogin.php', data=login_data)
print ra.content
print ra.headers
ans = dict(answer='5')
r=s.post('http://example/level1.php',data=ans)
print r.content
```

Just print the cookie to look up wheather you were logged.

```
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print (cookie.name, cookie.value)
```

And is the example site is yours?

If not maybe the site reject the bot/crawler !
And you can change your requests's user-agent as looks likes you are using a browser.

For example:

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36'
}
login_data = dict(userName='user', password='pwd')
ra=s.post('http://example/checklogin.php', data=login_data, headers=headers)
print ra.content
print ra.headers
ans = dict(answer='5')
r=s.post('http://example/level1.php',data=ans, headers = headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: Doesn't adding the user-agent headers override the headers which contain the logged in cookies? When I do this, I get a page, but it's not logged in...