# python - login with javascript support

Tags: python

I'm trying to login to a site using the requests library in Python.

In the returned html, I see "You must have javascript enabled to login". So, I test it in my browser with javascript disabled, and it says the same thing.

My question is, is there a library in Python that will allow me to login to a site while maintaining the session, that also supports javascript?

Comment: have you looked into mechanize ?

Comment: requests is a python lib to make sessions and http requests. see this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678066/consecutive-requests-with-python-requests-session-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678066/consecutive-requests-with-python-requests-session-not-working). also you taggued your question with javascript. does your question have something to do with javascript?

Comment: have you actually tried to log in via your python library? You will always see that message in the source code, it's just a browser with javascript enabled won't show it to the user.

Comment: @Red, yes I did, I got the response that I need javascript, karthikr I'm looking at that right now lynch, I'll remove that tag

Comment: @karthikr, I've just tried logging in with mechanize, but it gives me the same message. What do you think about Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

In the html, we use `<noscript>` tag to detect if the javascript is enabled.

```
<noscript>
    <div class="noscript">
        You must have javascript enabled to login
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Now most of websites use `ajax` to communicate with server asynchronously. So it need the javascript enabled.
In python you can use [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/),  [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)
[capserjs](http://casperjs.org/), [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/),  [pyv8](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/).

Also, you can capture the package use chrome web develepe tools . Then you can know what requests are send to the server. And you simulate the requests use `python requests` to get the expected response.