# Login to external page in browser using a Python request

Tags: python, django, http, session, authentication

I have a django webapp and authentificate via the requests module

```
import requests

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': "username",
    'password': "password"
}


r = requests.post('https://example.org/auth', data=payload)
print r.headers
print r.text
print r.cookies
```

That works fine. But how can I make the session persistent in the browser, i.e. I want to open another tab of example.org and be already signed in?

Edit: I know about 
You can easily create a persistent session using:

```
 s = requests.session()
```

The question is rather about how to make the session persistent between several requests or browser tabs, i.e. how to store the cookie jar in the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Requests and persistent sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737740/python-requests-and-persistent-sessions)

Comment: I want to call example.org/otherPage.html in another http request or even in another browser tab. Therefore the question is how to set the cookies so that the browser adds them in future requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/):

> Session Objects
>
> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance.

So you can do:

```
from requests import session
with session() as s:
    #connexion
    req = s.post('https://example.org/auth', data=payload)
    #get another page
    req = s.get('https://example.org/otherPage.html')
```

You can also get cookies from one request:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url)    
>>> r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
'example_cookie_value'
>>> req1Cookies = r.cookies
```

and send the cookies you want with another request:

To send your own cookies to the server, you can use the cookies parameter:

```
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working') 
>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

or

```
>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=req1Cookies)
```

Comment: I want to call https://example.org/otherPage.html in another http request or even in another browser tab. Therefore the question is how to set the cookies so that the browser sends them in future requests.

Comment: It is not about executing the future requests via python, it is about opening the site in the browser and being already signed in.

Comment: Then write the cookies to a file.

Comment: Can you give me more insight on this one? I just store the cookiejar in a specific file, and than my browser knows?

Comment: I can store the cookies to a file, but how does the browser know?

Comment: @MartinKapfhammer check where the browser stores its cookies for your site, and override this file