# Unable to use session within a classmethod of a web-scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I've created a python script using `classmethod` to fetch the `profilename` after `loging in` inputting the credentials in a webpage. The script is able to fetch the `profilename` in the right way. What I wish to do now is use `session` within `classmethod`. The `session` has already been defined within `__init__()` method. ***`I would like to keep the existing design intact`***.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class StackOverflow:

    SEARCH_URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

    def __init__(self,session):
        self.session = session

    @classmethod
    def crawl(cls,email,password):
        page = requests.get(cls.SEARCH_URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
        fkey = sauce.select_one("[name='fkey']")["value"]
        payload = {"fkey": fkey,"email": email,"password": password,}
        res = requests.post(cls.SEARCH_URL,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        user = soup.select_one("div[class^='gravatar-wrapper-']").get("title")
        yield user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        result = StackOverflow(s)
        for item in result.crawl("email", "password"):
            print(item)
```

***How can I use `session` taking from `__init__` within classmethod?***

Comment: This answer might help you .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737740/python-requests-and-persistent-sessions

Comment: I didn't create this post to learn how session works. I've a little knowledge on that. I wish to know how can I call session within classmethod fron init method. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do it from a class method - it doesn't have access to `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `self.session` from a class method. Method `__init__` is called when an instance of the class is created, however class methods are not bound to any particular instance of the class, but the class itself - that's why the first parameter is usually `cls` and not `self`.

You decided to create the session in the `__init__`, so it can be assumed that

```py
so1 = StackOverflow()
so2 = StackOverflow()
```

keep their sessions separate. If that is indeed your intention, the `crawl` method should not be annotated with `@classmethod`. If you have `crawl(self, email, pass):` then you will still be able to use `StackOverflow.SEARCH_URL` and `self.__class__.SEARCH_URL` to get the value defined in StackOverflow class, or `self.SEARCH_URL` which will by default get the same value, but could be changed with `so1.SEARCH_URL = "sth else"` (but `so2.SEARCH_URL` would keep it's original value)