# How to access the password protected Router Page from Python?

Tags: python, passwords, authorization

I want to fetch the page `192.168.1.1 /basic/home_dhcplist.htm`
 from the router but it asks for username and password at the start.

I am fetching the page in Python through urllib2

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.1/basic/home_dhcplist.htm')
html = response.read()
str="Prasads"
value= html.find(str)
print value
if value!=-1 :
    print "found"
else:
print "not found"

response.close()
```

Comment: router details would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every home router I have seen uses basic auth for authentication.  This is simply another header that you send along with the request.  Each time you request a page the username and password are sent as headers to the server, where they are verified each and every request.

I would suggest the `requests` library over `urllib2`.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://192.168.1.1/basic/home_dhcplist.htm', auth=('username', 'password'))

if 'Prasads' in r.text():
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

Comment: I solved the problem with authentication.
But can i get some automatic click of a button using requests?
Like some websites has i agree button.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to [set the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request) which maintains the session, most probably.

Access the page via a browser(Firefox) enter the login pass when prompted to do so.

Press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-k</kbd>, and reload the page and click on any of the most recent `GET` requests, you'll get a window showing the `GET` request details. Note the `Request Headers` and set the cookie accordingly.

The *key-value* which would be the most useful is `Authorization`.