# Python web request with redirect

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am attempting to scrape the following website flow.gassco.no as one of my first python projects. I need to bypass the splash screen which redirects to the main page. I have isolated the following action,

```
<form method="get" action="acceptDisclaimer">
<input type="submit" value="Accept"/> 
<input type="button" name="decline" value="Decline"  onclick="window.location = 'http://www.gassco.no'" />
</form>
```

In a browser appending 'acceptDisclaimer?' to the url redirects to the target flow.gassco.no. However if I try to replicate this in urllib, I appear to stay on the same page when outputting the source.

```
import urllib, urllib2
url="http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer?"
url2="http://flow.gassco.no/"
#first pass to invoke disclaimer
req=urllib2.Request(url)
res=urllib2.urlopen(req)
#second pass to access main page
req1=urllib2.Request(url2)
res2=urllib2.urlopen(req1)
data=res2.read()
print data
```

I suspect that I have oversimplified the problem, but would appreciate any input into how I can accept the disclaimer and continue to output the main page source.

Comment: Is this exactly what your code looks  like? Your urls are not quoted strings ("http://flow.gassco.no/") like they should be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a cookiejar. See [python: urllib2 how to send cookie with urlopen request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request)
2. Open the main url first
3. Open the /acceptDisclaimer after that