# Missing cookies in HTTP response Python

Tags: python, http, session, cookies, python-requests

I'm building an extra provider for Sickbeard and having problems with my cookies.
I've been looking for a long time now after why cookies are missing in the HTTP Response when using **requests**.

```
login_params = {'uid': sickbeard.PROVIDER_USERNAME,
                'pwd': sickbeard.PROVIDER_PASSWORD,
               }

try:
    response = self.session.post(self.urls['login'], data=login_params, timeout=30)
except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError), e:
    logger.log(u'Unable to connect to ' + self.name + ' provider: ' +ex(e), logger.ERROR)
    return False
```

The response only contains one cookie the ***__cdfuid*** cookie:

```
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)['__cfduid']
```

The cookies that I get (and want) when logging into the provider are ***__cdfuid*** | ***uid*** | ***pass***:

```
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)['__cfduid']
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)['uid'] #Not passed
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)['pass'] #Not passed
```

I don't know if it matters but the ***__cdfuid*** cookie is the only one that has *HttpOnly* and *path=/* parameters set. The other two just has expiration and the actual data.

Comment: what is `response.cookies`?

Comment: Only one param, **__cfduid** not the other two.

Comment: how do you know that `uid` and `pass` cookies are set?

Comment: When I look into the `response.text` I see that I successfully logged in, so I presume the cookies to be set. When I try the same post request in Chrome I get the header with the `uid` and `pass` cookies set.

Comment: successful login doesn't mean that `uid` and `pass` must be set. What happens if you clear cookies in Chrome before the request?

Comment: Same result, all the cookies are set as they should.

Comment: do the subsequent requests using `self.session` succeed?

Comment: No, that's the thing. The upcoming requests using `self.session` _(i.e. searching the provider)_ requires the cookies to be set. But because I can't get the complete set of cookies in the response, the cookies are not set, so hence the request fails.

Comment: you could use a network sniffer e.g., wireshark: to see the difference between Chrome and `requests` in this case.

Comment: This won't work, unfortunately. All traffic is encrypted through `HTTPS` requests. Maybe this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: Use any means that are convenient for you to see request/responses (browser tools, debug flags in `requests`, sslsniff). Do you see `secure` in the `Set-Cookie` header? Is `self.urls['login']` an https url?

Comment: No the `Set-Cookie` header does not contain any `secure` params. I can see that the request sent out from python is a `HTTP/1.0` and the one with chrome is `HTTP/1.1`. How would I go on by forcing the `self.session.post` to send a `HTTP/1.1` request instead?

Comment: `requests` is HTTP/1.1 client. If you see `HTTP/1.0` something is wrong. For debugging, try [`urllib2` client](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8206372/4279)

Comment: Ok, tried the same with `urllib2` and got the same results. It send out a `HTTP/1.0` request. Then I tried sending a `POST /takelogin.php HTTP/1.0` request using **cURL** _(Through the terminal)_ and got the cookies I wanted.. I don't get this?

Comment: Never mind my last comment. I ran the debugging they listed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/1052393) and got all information and it seems like it sends a `HTTP/1.1` with a `302 found` response. All the headers looks correct BUT I only get one cookie `__gfduid`.

Comment: So, I have no clue of what to do. Do you think there is something wrong with the host?

Comment: Try selenium webdriver or ghost.py to send the form and see whether you get the cookies

Answer (score 3):

`response.cookies` contains only the cookies set *by that response*. If you are redirected you may find some cookies were set by the redirect. These will not be present on `response.cookies`, though they will be present on `response.history[i].cookies`.

You should always examine the cookies dictionary on the `Session`, not the responses, if you want to get a full idea of what cookies have been set.

Comment: Yeah, but how is it that the I posted above uses `self.session` to get the cookies and it only returns the `__cfduid` cookie?

Comment: Check all of the history responses and confirm that the cookies were in fact set.