# How do I insert a cookie in Python for web scraping?

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping

I'm making a web scraper that I will host on my Raspberry Pi B, but the website I need to scrape from requires a cookie to access it. The specific cookie is .ROBLOSECURITY. I've logged in before using only that cookie (With the help of the EditThisCookie extension for Google Chrome). How do I make my Python program use this cookie to log in?

Here is my .ROBLOSECURITY cookie (Although a few letters/numbers were changed):

```
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
```

Here is a screenshot with some more info about the cookie.
[image: More info about this .ROBLOSECURITY cookie]

Comment: Also, can I just use the cookies that Chrome is using for my Python project (Like in VB where a web browser element uses the cookies you already have)?

Comment: What library are you using for the web scraping?

Comment: I'm using urllib and re

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can do it using the urllib.

```
import urllib2
handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel = 1)

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Cookie', (".ROBLOSECURITY=26D59EEB62BB82BA679D88E391F5E43448FDC5EEE74BEBBFD9879204EABA2813E4C00248E65D7ADBFE0B91F1B"
    "140E4DD61CBA1F0EE5991E5099BE044AD9AF0C019EFAFDCF6A41355002355A602F9B8ADEF4CD14E70825687F9748B082089DE69C833E4F5AE9B358F1988B3D3BB04CA5D0B"
    "F96501E8B4AAACD68BBE3ACCAED5DA646BB4E7B3D8CC88D102DD53382C8FE8696C54445EB3716AF08DF9816E14EAC0DA451C04803BAB801BF61A20FD9BF6E3FE9BF06833D"
    "68C08BB1DF4FDD3ED969687F42BAA5D57C66246549F4323F3FAE71D7E38574690F6AB41D56C224C949018C5C24901EB7D8A4B6D262A173B60B16B413F347B21AC8901F86D"
    "818B039A88344A324670D726176F42485ADE295EE22ADEDA733452735B043B7A4FF8262D42DF60D63329C77E8AF9EF65AD25B01CEAD48FCBF59D8CB70AE32BDE1651FB372"
    "656C600DBCBF53F0D49FB89275830B0A5513EC201C808699428C0F09BF8FE64A227D9A94B43943E2F81E252B45297D38AF6D8E8FDA180DCB491AA33FA7EE87BB1D1E00505"
    "0573294010E9169AB9AF716F69483128B93F87878C24380A57F64A8EF4BC9242A6125413548F88D15F6E6779A9B996BCADFEA7EABFEE3ED17EFEC148C33630CBCDCD9E1DD"
    "CB4B1C5DD42EF93C696C20D01A1E9D95AD40145ACE57C4664ACDF79EF78482DE6E40E7D3727C501A089993402F386A2D5997CDE530DBF93CDAD90E15F207D3B9DE168C3B6"
    "69E1099B304192CD33D327150A57B9383BDBC99215448F21"))

opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print resp.read()
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, now I can continue working on my web crawler.

Answer (score 6):

taken from [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

```
import requests
url = 'http://target_url'
cookies = dict(cookie='value')

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: "requests" is so good that it should be a standard feature for a next python iteration.

Comment: agreed, I find requests much easier to work with than standard python urllib