# Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online

Tags: python, python-2.7, sharepoint, urllib2, office365

I am attempting to write a script with [SharePoint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharepoint/0.3.2) package to access files on my company's SharePoint.  The tutorial states

> First, you need to create a `SharePointSite` object. We’ll assume you’re using basic auth; if you’re not, you’ll need to create an appropriate `urllib2` Opener yourself.

However, after several attempts, I've concluded that basic auth is not sufficient.  While researching how to try to make it work, I came upon [this article](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/) which gives a good overview of the general scheme of authentication.  What I'm struggling with is implementing this in Python.

I've managed to hijack the basic auth in the SharePoint module.  To do this, I took the XML message in the linked article and used it to replace the XML generated by the SharePoint module.  After making a few other changes, I now recieve a token as described in Step 2 of the linked article.

Now, in Step 3, I need to send that token to SharePoint with a POST.  The below is a sample of what it should look like:

```
POST http://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdomain.sharepoint.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Content-Length: [calculate]

t=EwBgAk6hB....abbreviated
```

I currently use the following code to generate my POST.  With the guidance from a few other questions, I've omitted the `content-length` header since that should be automatically calculated.  I was unsure of where to put the token, so I just shoved it in `data`.

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'mydomain.sharepoint.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)'
}

data = {'t':'{}'.format(token[2:])}
data = urlencode(data) 

postURL = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0"   
req = Request(postURL, data, headers) 
response = urlopen(req)
```

However, this produces the following error message:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

How do I generate a POST which will correctly return the authentication cookies I need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request  morten-jensen answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx) and [SharePoint Online authentication](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-authentication-77965e8d-48ad-47bd-a656-57f17d6d1cc7) articles :

> The Federation Authentication (FedAuth) cookie is for each top level
>   site in SharePoint Online such as the root site, the MySite, the Admin
>   site, and the Public site. The root Federation Authentication (rtFA)
>   cookie is used across all of SharePoint Online. When a user visits a
>   new top level site or another company’s page, the rtFA cookie is used
>   to authenticate them silently without a prompt.

To summarize, to acquire authentication cookies the request needs to be sent to the following endpoint:

```
url: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0  
method: POST
data: security token
```

Once the request is validated the response will contain authentication cookies (`FedAuth` and `rtFa`) in the HTTP header as explained in the article that you mentioned.

### SharePoint Online REST client for Python

As a proof of concept the [SharePoint Online REST client for Python](https://github.com/vgrem/SharePointOnline-REST-Python-Client) has been released which shows how to:

- perform remote authentication in SharePoint Online
- perform basic CRUD operations against SharePoint resources such as
  Web, List or List Item using REST API

**Implementation details**:

- [`AuthenticationContext.py` class](https://github.com/vgrem/SharePointOnline-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/client/AuthenticationContext.py) contains the *SharePoint
  Online remote authentication flow* implementation, in particular the
  `acquireAuthenticationCookie` function demonstrates how to handle
  authentication cookies
- [`ClientRequest.py` class](https://github.com/vgrem/SharePointOnline-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/client/ClientRequest.py) shows how to consume SharePoint Online REST API

**Examples**

The example shows how to read Web client object properties:

```
from client.AuthenticationContext import AuthenticationContext
from client.ClientRequest import ClientRequest

url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
username = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "password"


ctxAuth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctxAuth.acquireTokenForUser(username, password):
  request = ClientRequest(url,ctxAuth)
  requestUrl = "/_api/web/"   #Web resource endpoint
  data = request.executeQuery(requestUrl=requestUrl)

  webTitle = data['d']['Title']
  print "Web title: {0}".format(webTitle)

else:
  print ctxAuth.getLastErrorMessage()
```

More examples could be found under [examples](https://github.com/vgrem/SharePointOnline-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples) folder of GitHub repository

Comment: This is brilliant, one question though, is there any way to employ this where I can hand the good authentication back to the SharePoint module?

Comment: If I understood the question properly, you would like to pass auth context to [SharePoint module](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint), that's doable, but we we need to introduce a handler to pass with cookie to request. Note: the specified module consumes SharePoint Web Services API which Microsoft marked as [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#DeprecatedAPIs)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  While client does give me access wonderfully, I have no idea how to use it to check out and edit files.  While the SharePoint module has "limited support" at least I would have a starting point.  If we could jury-rig SharePoint module to use your client for authentication, that would be ideal, even if it is deprecated. However, now we're getting out of the scope of this question :)

Comment: Sample code here is outdated but [its repo has an updated readme](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/54).