# Cookie brute-force with python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, brute-force

I need to write a loop to brute force a cookie on a website,
and this is what I've got so far.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

i = 0
for i in range(75):
            opener.addheaders.append(('cookie',"cookie_name"+str(i)))
            REQ = opener.open("http://127.0.0.1:80/my_cookie")
            REQ.read()
```

It's actually changing the cookie, but it doesn't give the expected output. Any suggestions?

I tried a while loop and it's the same.  I think that the problem is in sending the cookie as a cookie!

second try

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

i = 75
while i > 0:
            opener.addheaders.append(('cookie','alien_id='+str(i)))
            print opener.open("http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore").read(2048)+str(i)
            i=i-1
```

Comment: The format of a cookie is `cookie_name=cookie_value`. You're missing the `=`.

Comment: i fixed that and it still not giving the expected response

Comment: How do you know it's changing the cookie if it's not giving the expected response?

Comment: by adding a print i

Comment: That shows that the variable is changing, it doesn't show that it's changing the cookie.

Comment: Your code is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request, I don't see why it doesn't work for you. Maybe the problem is with the `my_cookie` script?

Comment: What is the expected output, what are you getting instead?

Comment: Your script doesn't print the result of `REQ.read()`, how do you know the result is not what you expect?

Comment: i changed the 'REQ.read()' with 'print 'REQ.read()'

Comment: i'm now printing 'i' and printing the output , the expected output is a html code with 'you got it' in it but i'm receiving html code with 'give me a cookie' in it

Comment: Post the code of `my_cookie`.

Comment: i don't really have it

Comment: it's a web-based python challenges , a kind of CTF

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the cookie that it's looking for?

Comment: i can give you all details privately

Comment: You're still missing the `=` in your cookie in both versions of the code.

Comment: Why did you change from `cookie_name` to `alien_id`, and why did the URL change?

Comment: opener.addheaders.append(('cookie','alien_id='+str(i)))<< its there

Comment: # Write a script that can guess cookie values
# and send them to the url http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore
# Read the response from the right cookie value to get the flag.
# The cookie id the aliens are using is alien_id
# we believe the id is a number between 1 and 75

Comment: that's the whole thing

Comment: The `for` version is trying cookies from 0 to 74, not 1 to 75. But the `while` version looks correct to me.